# get parent element in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the parent element in a table. I have a checkbox and I want to check the checkbox  parent element.

For example

```
    <td> <a href="./index.html?p=10">$125.55</a> </td>
<td> <input type="checkbox" onChange="getValue(this);" /> </td>
```

In my getValue function, I would like to get the value 125.55. It will have multiples checkbox in the table inside a loop. Does anyone know how can I get this value? I can use JQuery or just JS.

Thanks

Comment: Please add the JavaScript/jQuery you tried to your question

Comment: add a class to a element and get value with jquery

Comment: you'd be better off using a select https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/d1rn6tsb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this snippet

```
function getValue(checkbox){
return checkbox.parentElement.parentElement.cells[0]
     .getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/21vdgoou/1/

```js
getValue = function(e){
 console.log($($(e).parent().prev().children()[0]).text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td> <a href="./index.html?p=10">$125.55</a> </td>
  <td> <input type="checkbox" onChange="getValue(this);" /> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <a href="./index.html?p=10">$195</a> </td>
  <td> <input type="checkbox" onChange="getValue(this);" /> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <a href="./index.html?p=10">$155</a> </td>
  <td> <input type="checkbox" onChange="getValue(this);" /> </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```